# Importing an Rcpp header file in NAMESPACE within an R Package

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

This is my first package in *R*, I already have working package but I would remove some rewriting function in cpp file, so I do an header file that work with single function.

How can I put this header in package? 
Note that `header.h` and `header.cpp` are in `src/` directory of package 
and the `#include "header.h"` is in the `.cpp` file where I use this function

I tried to modify the `NAMESPACE` file with:

```
import(myheader)
```

But, when I do:

```
R CMD INSTALL mypackage
```

I receive this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'mypackage' in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: myheader
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Why do you want to put this in the `NAMESPACE`? This file is for imported and exported R functions, not for C++ functions/headers/... Adding the file to `src` directory is all that should be needed.

Comment: thank you very very much, i didn't think about it !!

Comment: You may want to consider looking at some example packages on CRAN.  RcppExamples is an obvious one, there are many others that are not too complicated.

Answer (score 5):

As @RalfStubner pointed out in the comments, the `NAMESPACE` file is meant for exporting and importing *R* functions and data.

The primary requirement for a `NAMESPACE` files in a package using *Rcpp* is to ensure:

1. A single function from *Rcpp* package is **imported** for registration reasons.

   - Generally, either `evalCpp` or `sourceCpp` is used.
2. Provide the name of the shared object via [`useDynLib()`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#useDynLib),

   - This is the name of the *R* package being built.

```
importFrom(Rcpp, sourceCpp)
useDynLib(<PACKAGE_NAME_HERE>, .registration = TRUE)
```

where `<PACKAGE_NAME_HERE>` is the name of the package without `<>`.

---

If you're interested in using headers to share code between *R* packages, consider looking at:

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-shared-cpp-functions

The main design pattern is using `inst/include` directory to place a header-only library. Then, in `src/` write bindings to the library. Ensure that `src/Makevars` and `src/Makevars.win` has:

```
# Register where the header files for the package can be found
PKG_CXXFLAGS=-I../inst/include/
```

---

If you want to share function definitions between `.cpp` files in the same *R* package, see:

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-headers-src

This avoids a single monolithic `.cpp` file, but does not allow for sharing the compiled code routines between *R* packages outside of the exported *R* wrapper.